# Where in the world is my SuperUser t-shirt?

Tags: support, t-shirt

I filled in the form to receive my SuperUser t-shirt on April 8th, but I haven't received it yet. It's been more than a month. Is there any way to learn if it's on its way to Istanbul?

**EDIT:**
Today is 28th of June, and I haven't received my t-shirt yet. What took [Poirot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercule_Poirot) so long to solve the crime on the train from Istanbul to Paris? I want my t-shirt before the summer's gone...

Comment: (not constantinople.)

Comment: I believe there was some issue with a murder on the train to Paris.  Your shirt should resume it's travel as soon as Poirot solves the crime and the train is able to make the return trip.

Comment: +1 @tvanfosson Poirot FTW!

Comment: @tvanfosson are you saying Mehper is going to get a bloody T-Shirt with a hole in it?

Comment: @Questions - 12 bloody holes, to be precise.

Comment: Make your own! See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45782/t-shirt-time-beta/45812#45812

Comment: Just arrived! W00t!

Comment: whhen will these get back? :(

Comment: But it's free... why would you complain about how long it takes someone to do something nice for you?

Comment: @Kara: Don't take this as complaining. I just wanted to know if I will ever get it or not. If I won't, I might try to create my own t-shirt because I'd love to wear a t-shirt having the Superuser logo.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, I hope it shows up soon.  ;)

Comment: Where is the flair from it? :(

Comment: Can't believe nobody has said this... You'll get it in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: The murder Poiroit solved was on the train from Istanbul to Paris, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just received my t-shirt today. Special thanks to Jeff, Robert, and Emily.

Answer (score 8):

Alex is still working on them. Sorry for the delays.

edit: they are now shipping as I type this! Visual proof!

[image]

(again, we apologize for the long delay!)

Comment: Never underestimate the time it takes to sew.

Comment: I'd almost downvote this answer, simply for making me wait!

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. Can't wait to wear it!

Comment: I haven't yet received mine. Any idea? Can't wait to wear it either.

Answer (score 6):

I talked to [Alex Papadimoulis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/133733/alex-papadimoulis) and he said there was a delay within the company we are using for fulfillment. T-shirts are going out now and we should be all caught up within the next two weeks.

The first priority is to get the current orders filled. After that, we are looking at ways to improve the process to make it smoother/quicker. I want my Super User t-shirt!

Comment: (I previously commented here that I didn't get mine yet, but it was actually my **webmasters** SE t-shirt I was referring to, and .. it just arrived! I was confused. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are the T-shirts (still) lost in shipment ? I haven't gotten mine yet.

Comment: I've gotten many twitter reports of users (in far-off countries, even) getting their SU and SF shirts in the last few days..

Comment: I got mine in Australia on Friday. It took ~14 days to get here, so I'm guessing they were shipped ~2 weeks ago.

Comment: @Jeff I'm in India. To complicate matters we've shifted to a new location (last week). I hope the security will forward the T shirt to the new office. Else, its gone :\

Comment: I haven't received my t-shirt either.

Comment: Neither have I, even though I have heard of other users in germany receiving them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the proper place, but I was told I was getting a jQuery shirt about 3-4 months now and I've yet to receive it. I did receive my SO shirt, though.

It's hard to complain about not getting free crap, but I am wondering if it is on its way...

Comment: If it helps the same is true here, like you I wouldn't complain either way, but if it helps to know you're not crazy...you're not :)

Comment: @Nick-Craver - I mailed John Resig about this he said- "We're working on setting up a jQuery store with t-shirts, once that's
up we'll be able to easily send out the shirts to the contributors.
(We wanted to have their names and addresses ready for when it was
time to actually send them out.) "

Answer (score 0):

I have mine. I plan to wear it to a local dev conference in August.